# Can't serve to HTTP websites, using HTTPS instead does work

Tags: apache-2.4

I am running into a strange problem. But, first. This is my server configuration

CentOS 6
Apache 2.4.41
DirectAdmin 1.59.5

When I visit my website over HTTP http://koenhollander.nl/ (my personal website), I see a default Apache notification about the correct installation instead of the website.

But when I visit my website over HTTPS, https://koenhollander.nl/ - it does work as expected.

I did'nt change anything to my config and every website on the whole website is experiencing the same problem.

What I have done:

- I already tried to rebuild Apache
- I tried to rewrite the configs

Both where succesful, but I still can't visit my website over HTTP

Does someone know a good way to troubleshoot this problem (so I can solve it)?

Comment: Can you access Apache's config? `apache2ctl -DDUMP_CONFIG` will dump the configuration. The problem probably lies in your `<VirtualHost>` configurations, please add them to your question. Add also `apache2ctl -S`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thanks for the comment, after the command -S i found the mistake (was rewritten to port 8080 instead of 80)

Comment: Great. Please consider adding an answer yourself regarding this port misconfiguration. Takes the question off the list without answers.